# setState is not correctly updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a function that adds sub varieties to an array of varieties i.e each variety is an object having a property called varieties which is an array of objects also.

the initial varieties state is

```
const defaultInitVarieties = [];

const [varieties, setVarieties] = useState(defaultInitVarieties);
```

addInner is declared as:

```
const addInner = (newEntry, parentId) => {
console.log('running add inner');
//copy varieties
let copy = [...varieties];
// get parent via id
let parent = copy.find(each => each.id === parentId);
// get index of parent
const index = copy.findIndex(each => each.id === parentId);
//create new color variety
const newParent = {
  ...parent,
  varieties: [
    ...parent.varieties,
    {
      index: parent.varieties.length < 1 ? 0 : parent.varieties.length,
      edit: false,
      ...newEntry,
    }
  ]
};
//mutate copy
console.log('copy before', copy)
copy[index] = newParent;
console.log('copy after', copy);
//update state
setVarieties(copy);
};
```

**PROBLEM**

bearing in mind that varieties has one object in the array, the results of console.log('copy after', copy); is;

```
[{
   id: "31943632-0f91-419c-b6ee-55a3d92fdd28"
   imageUrl: "/static/media/choose-image.ba6e31d9.svg"
   size: "24"
   quantity: 1
   price: "2000"
   discountPrice: "2000"
   color: "red"
   varieties: [
    {
      index: 0
      edit: false
      id: "eb351fff-4216-4080-8cc2-31e677aa5b0e"
      imageUrl: "/static/media/choose-image.ba6e31d9.svg"
      size: "22"
      quantity: 1
      price: "2000"
      discountPrice: "2000"
      color: "red"
    }
   ]
  }]
```

which is what I expect.

**However**, when I setVariety with that what I get is

```
[{
  id: "31943632-0f91-419c-b6ee-55a3d92fdd28"
  imageUrl: "/static/media/choose-image.ba6e31d9.svg"
  size: "24"
  quantity: 1
  price: "2000"
  discountPrice: "2000"
  color: "red"
  varieties: []
},
{
  id: "eb351fff-4216-4080-8cc2-31e677aa5b0e"
  imageUrl: "/static/media/choose-image.ba6e31d9.svg"
  size: "22"
  quantity: 1
  price: "2000"
  discountPrice: "2000"
  color: "red"
  varieties: []
}]
```

i.e the newEntry addition is added as another variety instead of it being a subvariety!

Comment: The data from after `setVariety`, where did that come from? Do you have another console.log that's not visible? Also the GUID actually appears to match your original "parent" entry, not the child entry you're adding...which is of course still a problem, but maybe a different problem.

Comment: thanks, @David784, the same GUID is a typo from me when writing the question, also I don't understand what u meant by data after setVariety.

Comment: Where are you printing out the state after calling `setVarieties()`?

Comment: I'm not, it's from the components tab in dev tools

Comment: I made a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-elbakyan-dqxfm?file=/src/App.js) with as close to your code above as I could get, and it seems to work properly. Is there something different in my sandbox from what you're doing?

Comment: thanks David... I think i just spotted my error... it's embarrassing... its elsewhere in the code thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `setVarieties(newParent);` instead of `setVarieties(copy);`. If you want to see the expected change in console then change `copy[index] = newParent;` to `copy = newParent;` with this you won't need to change `setVarieties(copy);` statement.

Comment: thanks Ketan, however, newParent is an item in the varieties array which happens to contain an array of sub-varieties, setting the whole varieties to that will not be right.

Comment: If I am correct copy is a javascript object (as per your console.log) so copy[index] = newParent; does not feel the right way to do this.

Comment: my bad, its an array containing a single object